Decay estimate for a heat-like kernel.
Consider a integral kernel $G(x,t)$, which satisfies
$$\hat G(\xi ,t)\le Ce^{-c|\xi|^2t},$$
for some positive constant $c,C>0$.
I want to show that it satisfies the following decay estimate for derivatives:
$$\lVert  \partial_x^\alpha G(x,t)\rVert_{L^p}\le C(1+t)^{-(1-\frac 1p+\frac \alpha 2)}.$$
I know it holds for heat kernel $G=e^{t\Delta}$. When I try to modify the proof for $e^{t\Delta}$ to a more general kernel satisfy the above condition, I find it is difficult since the proof use the explicit form of $e^{t\Delta}=(4\pi t)^{-\frac d2}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{t}}$. So can anyone explain why the claim holds for the kernels satisfying the multiplier condition?

What do you mean by the multiplier condition?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend I means the condition $\hat G(\xi,t)\le Ce^{-c|\xi|^2t}$.
